# Use a variable table name for Entity Framework SqlQuery to fetch data into entity Class

Tags: c#, linq, generics, entity-framework-6

I want to convert string var to entity framework class but I don't now how.
I have searched a lot but can not found anything

```
public JsonResult GetReports(string tbl)
{
    using (Context db = new Context())
    {
        // *** Problem is that tbl is string and I want to Cast tbl 
        //     to Users Class OR eny of  my other Class 
        var result= db.Database.SqlQuery<tbl>("SELECT * FROM Users");
        return Json(new { data = result});
    }
}

public partial class Users
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Gender { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }      
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

The reason of way I want to do something like that is I want to crete some dynamic method and `tbl` can be any of my table names (As a string)

Comment: tbl is string var it is the problem i want to create dynamic method and i have table name as string i want to convert string varable to Users Class

Comment: You can’t do that by default. You can create a switch/case structure that takes the string and creates the correct class instance. But you have to know them beforehand.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen its not bad idea I'm thinking about it before but i wonder if its have better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generic Approach**

Given that you have strongly named classes (like `Users`), there should be no reason to resort to weak or dynamic approaches.

For example, if the requirement is to build a generic repository Query capability, which DRY's up the data access code and possibly introduces common cross cutting concerns like logging, instrumentation, possibly retries, and exception handling, then you can use a generic wrapper around `SqlQuery<T>`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> TypedQuery<T>(string myQuery)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext(ConnString))
        {
            return await db.Database
                .SqlQuery<T>(myQuery)
                .ToListAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error here
        // Consider if the query can be retried
        // Consider whether the exception should be propogated or swallowed
        // Should the return type extended to indicate success / failure
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

Which you can invoke like so, using the generic type parameter to indicate the type of the target `POCO` (`Users` in this case):

```
var repo = new MyRepo();
var myUsers = await repo.TypedQuery<Users>("SELECT Id, Name FROM Users");
```

The benefit is that `myUsers` is a strongly typed collection.

**Dynamic Approach**

In theory it is possible to use the [`Type` overload of `SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%28System.Type,System.String,System.Object[]%29) to answer your original question. You can either pass in a `System.Type` directly, or I guess you could map some other key abstraction to the type, such as this:

```
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type> MyTypeMap 
= new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    { "users", typeof(Users)},
    { "foo", typeof(Foo)},
    ... other type maps here
};

public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> WeakQuery(string someType, string someQuery)
{
    Type typeOfMyClass;
    if (MyTypeMap.TryGetValue(someType, out typeOfMyClass))
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext(ConnString))
        {
            return await db.Database.SqlQuery(typeOfMyClass, someQuery)
                .ToListAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            // The problem now is that you get an untyped DbRawSqlQuery
        }
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<object>();
}
```

The problem is though is because of the weak typing that you would need to either re-cast the result, or work with dynamic, which will make for very fragile code when used, such as :

```
var repo = new MyRepo();
dynamic x = await repo.WeakQuery("users", "SELECT Id, Name, Gender FROM Users");
Assert.IsNotNull(x);
Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.First(x).Name == "Foo");
```

- Try to avoid `SELECT *` - instead, select all of the columns explicitly to map into the `Users` class.

Comment: tanx for reply.  i read bout  post before but i don't want use any of dose because its not work for me i want to create dynamic method and i need to tbl var be a generic class or something like that

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me - you have a strong, well defined class `Users`, so why on earth would you want to go dynamic? `SqlQuery<T>` is a generic overload, so you are free to build your own generic wrapper around it. The dynamic workaround links above use the other overload, viz `SqlQuery(Type, ..)`

Comment: I've updated the answer. in my opinion, the whole point of `SqlQuery` is like `Dapper`, to be quickly able to deserialize rows into a strongly typed object. If you resort to weak typing, you are probably better off with a `SqlDataReader` and pulling out the fields by ordinal value.

Comment: Tanx I left my workstation but I think that is my answer. I let you now tomorrow  if it's worked for me  :)

Comment: thank you very much. i learn tow things from you. bout approach are good and handy i use second one but remember the first one